# Why is there a get http/1.1 packet on a https website?

Tags: http, firefox, https, wireshark

I typed amazon.com on the mozilla search bar and hit enter, the goal was to observe the exchanged packets through wireshark.
But strangely just after the TCP handshake there is a GET HTTP/1.1 packet. After the HTTP/1.1 get packet there is a HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently packet from amazon server. Amazon must surely be using HTTPS. My question is why is there a GET HTTP/1.1 request is it because I typed amazon.com and not https://amazon.com? Is this the default behaviour of Firefox?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I might read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit this question.

Answer (score 0):

After analysing the packets, I concluded that the default behaviour of google-chrome and mozilla when you type example.com is to establish a tcp connection on port 80 and send get request to http://example.com , if the website used https like it was in my case, it will respond with and http response of status 301 (moved permanently) which includes the correct address (https://example.com)